# android:how to Reload the TabActivity when tab press?

Tags: android

I have Tab Based Application where i want to Reload the Tab activity when tab are select again.. In my application when i select the Tab again the view are coming as old output It is not reloading the page..so how can i reload the page by clicking the Tab again and again without showing old view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

switching of tabs calls onPause and onResume functions, so in order to refresh the page, cut paste the functionality provided in onCreate to onResume...

Comment: Farhan i cant understand what you want to tell me ..So please give me a example code so i can understand .........Thanks a lot for answer

Comment: lets say your functionality for tab a is "Show(a)" and for tab b is "Show(b)" and you have written these lines in onCreate() of both activities... now switching wont call again these functions so in order to again call your functionalities, put these functions in onResume() function just like you put it in onCreate().... hope it helps...